# MVC 4, WebApi: POST stopped working, GET working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I can no longer do POSTs to the WebAPI in MVC 4. The Post() method, however I make it, will not be invoked. If I send a GET, there are no problems at all.

```
public void Post()
{
}
```

That is how simple it is in the controller. I use Fiddler to send the Post, but no reaction. I use fiddler to send a GET to the same controller, and the GET method gets invoked.

I have looked around for hours, but cannot figure out where the problem is, let alone where to do the debugging, because any POST simply has a 500 (Internal Server Error) returned.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: And when you inspect the raw response payload in Fiddler what exactly do you see? You mentioned something about a 500 error, what's the server response body to your POST request?

Comment: "Multiple actions were found that match the request" - you are getting me on the right track. I'll follow that and report back.

Comment: Could you show your route definitions and controller?

Comment: Problem was this: I had two more methods in the controller, one called GatherZipCode() and another called RetrieveWeather(). I thought they had no influence on handling POST, since they did not have the Post keyword in them. But they confused it all, and the reason for the problems. Thanks to Darin Dimitrov, who led me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two more methods in the controller, one called GatherZipCode() and another called RetrieveWeather(). I thought they had no influence on handling POST, since they did not have the Post keyword in them. But they confused it all, and the reason for the problems. So watch out for having more than one handler of a Post in the api controller.

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov, who led me on the right track.

Comment: thats kinda confusing, but it works for me. i had a method on controller, and at beginning GET, POST, PUT... it all works, suddently POST stop. well, thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

add a method atrribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference. It is a WebApi in MVC 4, inheriting ApiController, so there is no need to decorate with [HttpPost], as long as the method name starts with Post().